# Does calling an asynchronous Hook trigger multiple requests?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

Imagine the following components:

```js
function useAsyncHook() {
  async function doAsyncStuff() {
    ...
  }

  doAsyncStuff();
}

function Foo() {
  const result = useAsyncHook();

  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  );
}

function App() {
  const result = useAsyncHook();

  return (
    <>
      <Foo/>
      ...
    </>
  );
}
```

Note that `App` includes `Foo` in its nested components. Sorry if this is a silly question, but how many network requests are there? Only one, which is implicitly cached, or two, one for each component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have two network requests, custom hooks don't share state.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook)

> **Do two components using the same Hook share state?** No. Custom Hooks are a mechanism to reuse stateful logic (such as setting up a subscription and remembering the current value), but every time you use a custom Hook, all state and effects inside of it are fully isolated.